# How to preserve const correctness of the C++ COM object's implementation class?

Tags: c++, com, atl, idl, const-correctness

It is considered a good practice to be const correct within C++ code base. However, it is hard to preserve it when COM objects comes into play. Consider the following excerpt of the IDL file (*Sample.idl*):

```
interface ISampleObject : IDispatch
{
     HRESULT GetData(LONG* plData);
};
```

The interface defined above is transformed into the C++ pure abstract class by the MIDL compiler. It's definition is shown below (*Sample_i.h*):

```
ISampleObject : public IDispatch
{
public:
    virtual /* [id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetData( 
        /* [out] */ LONG *plData) = 0; 
};
```

Notice that the pure abstract class above contains member function *GetData* which is not marked as *const*. This is nothing unusual considering that IDL file does not contain any information about it. In fact, all COM objects consumed from the C++ client application cannot utilize const correctness because COM simply doesn't support it, too bad. Notice, that this problem could be solved using a simple wrapper around the object.

However, the problem which I would like to tackle is preservation of const correctness for C++ COM object's implementation class. Consider the following excerpt of code (*SampleObject.h*) which utilizes the ATL facilities to implement the *ISimpleObject* interface:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSampleObject :
     public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
     public CComCoClass<CSampleObject, &CLSID_SampleObject>,
     public IDispatchImpl<ISampleObject, &IID_ISampleObject, &LIBID_SampleLib, 1,  0>
{
// Implementation details...
private:
    long m_lData;

public:
    CSampleObject() { m_Data = 10; }

    STDMETHOD(GetData(LONG* plData))
    {
        return *plData = m_lData, S_OK;
    }
};
```

Now, one can imagine accessing the *CSampleObject* object using the const pointer to that object. A not very useful example is shown below (a more practical example would pass the *pSampleObj* const pointer to some class).

```
// Somewhere in the C++ COM object's implementation class
void NoOneWritesSmthLikeThisInProd()
{
    const CSampleObject* pSampleObj = this;
    long lData = -1;
    pSampleObj->GetData(&lData); // Compile-time error
}
```

The idea is to tell the compiler that the *GetData* member function is const, so it can be accessed through the const pointer. There are a couple of solutions which comes into my mind:

1. Use const_cast operator to cast away constness of the object. This solution violates the whole idea behind the const correctness. In fact the only advantage of it is that it works - not much more.

   ```
   const_cast<CSampleObject*>(pObj)->GetData(&lData);
   ```
2. Introduce the secondary interface which replicates all of the member functions which are intended to be const, from the MIDL generated file (*Sample_i.h*). Then let the implementation class inherit from it (along with the original *ISampleObject* interface).

   ```
   class ISampleObjectConst
   {
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetData(LONG* plData) const = 0;
   };

   class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSampleObject :
       public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
       public CComCoClass<CSampleObject, &CLSID_SampleObject>,
       public IDispatchImpl<ISampleObject, &IID_ISampleObject, &LIBID_SampleLib,  1, 0>,
       public ISampleObjectConst
   {
   // Implementation details...
   public:
       STDMETHOD(GetData(LONG* plData))
       {
           return static_cast<const CSampleObject*>(this)->GetData(plData);
       }

       STDMETHOD(GetData(LONG* plData)) const 
       {
           return *plData = m_lData, S_OK;
       }
   };
   ```

   This solution boils down to one function calling another. Non-const version is used for COM object function calls, on the other hand const version is used for non-COM object function calls. The drawback of this solution is that it requires a great deal of repetition. Is it worth it?
3. Modify the MIDL-generated pure abstract class member function so it is marked as const. Then it is possible code COM object's class in a const correct manner just as a regular C++ class. However, there are two drawbacks of this solution, i.e.:

   1. The MIDL-generated file (*Sample_i.h*) is about to be re-created every time the IDL file (*Sample.idl*) changes, hence the introduced const keywords will disappear causing further compilation errors. This can be solved using some post IDL compiler processing (running a script which would put const keywords in the correct places).
   2. I'm not sure whether changing the auto-generated file is something that I can relay on in the production, especially if out-of-process and remote calls are considered. I have tested that it works with in-process servers using C++ and C# clients. Based on my tests it seems that the (in-process) client doesn't care about the modifications described above. Is it true for every case?

To clarify the question. I'd like to get some feedback on solutions presented above. Perhaps someone already made the ATL\COM C++ code const correct? Any other solution would be appreciated.

Comment: COM is a binary contract. C++ is "just" one of the possible target languages for it, even midl/idl is an option (that we use in general of course). A COM interface is an abstract virtual "contract" that has no concept of "constness" of the underlying class (and methods). Why do you have such a need for const classes for C++ classes implementing COM interfaces?

Comment: As I mentioned _a more practical example would pass the pSampleObj const pointer to some class_. Notice that this other class is a pure C++ class which might  by design disallow to change any content's of the object, e.g. a class which reads the data in order to cache it in some custom format for a later use. As a C++ class implementer I would like to say to the people who will maintain this class in the future 'Hey, you have a const pointer so you are disallowed to modify the object'. It is all about good **C++** practices, now the compiler guards whether the object is modified.

Comment: Usually, a COM interface represents only a portion of what you library does, and does this in a language-agnostic way, since it's binary. I probably wouldn't use "pure C++ classes" to expose my library to COM, or/and admit that COM is not "pure C++" (and has no idea of what a const object is). It's very common to create other classes just to expose parts of your code to the world as COM and code the holy heart of your library the way you see fit, with the language and details/constraints of your choice. In terms of maintenance, it has also its benefits (decoupling, versioning, ...).